# Form how to find() the email and password inputs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form to submit data through a `$.post()` in jQuery. The PHP file returns a response in this format:

```
header('Content-type: javascript/json');
echo json_encode(['state' => true, 'message' => 'Some Message']);
exit;
```

Which looks like this when encoded and works fine:

```
{state: true, message: 'Some Message'}
```

However, I cannot send the form fields. I have tried using the `find()` function but it returns `undefined` in the console.

**Here is my code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var Member = {

    login_form: $('#login'),
    create_form: $('#register'),
    response: false,
    response_message: '',

    login: function() {
      var email = this.login_form.find('input[type=email]').val();
      var password = this.create_form.find('input[type=password]').val();
      this.request('/members/login', {
        email: email,
        password: password
      });
    },
    create: function() {
      var email = this.create_form.find('input[type=email]').val();
      var password = this.create_form.find('input[type=password]').val();
      this.request('/members/create', {
        email: email,
        password: password
      });
    },
    request: function(uri, params) {
      $.post(uri, params)
        .done(function(r) {
          Member.response = r.state;
          if (!r.state) {
            Member.response_message = r.message;
          }
        });
    },
    getEmail: function() {
     return this.create_form.find('input[type=email]').val();
    },
    getPassword: function() {
     return this.create_form.find('input[type=password]').val();
    }

  };
  
  $('#submit').click(function() {
   Member.login();
    console.log('[L_CTRL] Response : ' + Member.response_message);
    console.log('[L_CTRL] Email : ' + Member.getEmail());
    console.log('[L_CTRL] Password : ' + Member.getPassword());
  });

});
```

```css
input {
  margin: 5px;
  background: none;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 80%;
}

button {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>
Login
</h1>
<form id='login'>
<input type='email' placeholder='Enter your email address...'>
<input type='password' placeholder='Enter your unique password...'>
<button type='button' id='submit'>
Go
</button>
</form>
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction to accessing the `val()` of the input fields? Thank-you.

Update: I do not want to directly find it using its ID, ie:

```
$('#email').val();
```

Because the ID's can change from form to form.

Comment: Your PHP output is a JSON object. not HTML. It is only able to get state and message values.

Comment: I would suggest creating your form correctly with labels and input names and id's then you can just get the values with e.g. `$('#login-email').val()` otherwise you're creating a non semantic form which for the most part will be inaccessible to some users

Comment: I can't because we have multiple login forms on one page, I know I could use classes but it would still have to use familiar methods like `nearest()` therefore, I found the `find()` easier since I only need to know which form they clicked which again, will become a class (`.login-form`) @JezEmery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this two functions as follow :

```
    getEmail: function() {
        console.log();
        return this.login_form.find('input[type=email]').val();
    },
    getPassword: function() {
        return this.login_form.find('input[type=password]').val();
    }
```

Comment: the only wrong thing is you are using "create_form" instead of "login_form" in both this functions

Comment: oh, I can't believe I've sat here that long to not notice that.. Thank-you!

Answer (score 3):

Replace `create_form` with `login_form`, because you're now selecting the register form, not the login form:

```
getEmail: function() {
    return this.login_form.find('input[type=email]').val();
  },
  getPassword: function() {
    return this.login_form.find('input[type=password]').val();
  }
```

Full code:

```js
  var Member = {

    login_form: $('#login'),
    create_form: $('#register'),
    response: false,
    response_message: '',

    login: function() {
      var email = this.login_form.find('input[type=email]').val();
      var password = this.create_form.find('input[type=password]').val();
      this.request('/members/login', {
        email: email,
        password: password
      });
    },
    create: function() {
      var email = this.create_form.find('input[type=email]').val();
      var password = this.create_form.find('input[type=password]').val();
      this.request('/members/create', {
        email: email,
        password: password
      });
    },
    request: function(uri, params) {
      $.post(uri, params)
        .done(function(r) {
          Member.response = r.state;
          if (!r.state) {
            Member.response_message = r.message;
          }
        });
    },
    getEmail: function() {
     return this.login_form.find('input[type=email]').val();
    },
    getPassword: function() {
     return this.login_form.find('input[type=password]').val();
    }

  };
  
  $('#submit').click(function() {
   Member.login();
    console.log('[L_CTRL] Response : ' + Member.response_message);
    console.log('[L_CTRL] Email : ' + Member.getEmail());
    console.log('[L_CTRL] Password : ' + Member.getPassword());
  });
```

```css
input {
  margin: 5px;
  background: none;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 80%;
}

button {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>
Login
</h1>
<form id='login'>
<input type='email' placeholder='Enter your email address...'>
<input type='password' placeholder='Enter your unique password...'>
<button type='button' id='submit'>
Go
</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to access the response before receive it, you should get the values in the success callback, try :

```
.done(function(r) {
  Member.response = r.state;
  if (!r.state) {
    Member.response_message = $.parseJSON(r.message);

    console.log('[L_CTRL] Response : ' + Member.response_message);
    console.log('[L_CTRL] Email : ' + Member.getEmail());
    console.log('[L_CTRL] Password : ' + Member.getPassword());
  }
});
```

Take a look to [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

**NOTE :** you've to parse the response, using  **[`$.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)** :

```
Member.response_message = $.parseJSON(r.message);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did not even come across that yet since I wasn't returning a message for the time being - you fixed a later issue, appreciated!